# add arraylist of lat/lng along with string ,string and int(id) of the mapping

Tags: android

I have added all lat/lng to arraylist and .Iwould like to map it to string name and another string along with its id which is an int .Basically I would like to get :

Association : (arraylist)-->Name---->Another Name------>id

how do I do the above association.I am a noob in android and I am using hashmap but it only puts(key,value) which does not satisfy the above condition.

Please let me know how I can implement the above requirement. 
I appreciate any help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could accomplish this. Here are two different ways off the top of my head:

Create an object that will hold the two names and id. Then create a hashmap that maps each lat/long value to the appropriate object. The prototype would be like:

```
HashMap<Long/Lat, Object>
```

Or if you don't want to create a new object, then create a hashmap that maps each lat/long value to a hashmap that contains the two names and id. The prototype would be like:

```
HashMap<Long/Lat, HashMap<String, String>>
```

Comment: Hello btse thank you for your input.I already have lat/lng in arraylist I just want to add name,name2,int to the each complete set of arraylist(lat/lng).

Comment: @jason Is there a reason why you can't change the structure? There's nothing you can do with an already existing arraylist unless you want to do some text parsing or something.

Comment: I can change it but there are many lat/lng points and many arrays within arrays.